# Redirecting from Custom Admin Page Produces "Headers already sent"

Tags: wordpress

I've registered a custom Admin page in my plugin through `add_submenu_page`. In the callback function (the one that generates the contents of the admin page), I have the following code:

```
wp_redirect('http://google.com');
exit;
```

However, when I visit the admin page I get an error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ..\wp-admin\includes\template.php:1637) in ..\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 878
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The callback from `add_submenu_page` happens too late (after the admin sidebar and header are rendered), this is why the `location` header can not be sent anymore.

To accomplish this, we need to hook a function a bit earlier in the WordPress admin area, before the headers are sent (e.g. `admin_init`).

A good way:

```
function myplugin_preprocess_pages($value){
    global $pagenow;
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : false);
    if($pagenow=='admin.php' && $page=='myplugin-custom-page-slug'){
        wp_redirect('http://google.com');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'myplugin_preprocess_pages');
```

The above code will redirect you to Google whenever you try to view `wp-admin/admin.php?page=myplugin-custom-page-slug`.

In my case, I've attached the custom page via `add_submenu_page` to the default (admin.php) parent in the Admin area and I've set the custom page's slug to `myplugin-custom-page-slug`. Feel free to replace the values in the code above or even add a PHP `switch` if you have a lot of custom admin pages.

This way we have hooked early enough to do a redirection whenever our custom admin page is viewed.

***Update:*** (A different approach)

Thanks to [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/88283/27981), I've learned that WordPress creates a unique action that you can hook to for each custom admin page (`load-{parent_page_slug}_page_{plugin_subpage_slug}`). For example, if you've added a custom admin page with parent `admin.php` and slug `myplugin-custom-page`, you can hook to its "load" action in the following manner:

```
add_action( 'load-admin_page_myplugin-custom-page', 'myplugin_custom_page_redirect' );
function myplugin_custom_page_redirect() {
    if ( 'myplugin-custom-page' == filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'page' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://google.com' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Note that the action name has some things to consider. It's a mixture of underscores and dashes and make sure you only include the parent page's name without the extension (so "admin" instead of "admin.php")